# OPencv error - NCV Asssertion failed. Need solutions to correct this

Tags: opencv, face-detection, haar-classifier, adaboost

OPenCV Error : GPU Api call NCV Assertion failed : NCV Stat=28, file=...\cascadeclassifier.cpp line=168> in unknown function, file ....\cascadeclassifier.cpp line 202

I am getting this error when i run my detection program

Comment: where are all the magicians when you need them? Come and take a look at this bloke's question and suggest a solution. Seriously though, you need to provide a bit more than the final log. Detect the code which is causing issue and share it here with the community

Comment: <NCV ASsertion failed:NCV Stat=28, file..\cascadeclassifier.cpp line=168

Comment: That's very helpful. We now know line 168 and 202 are being very mean. You need to share code mate. Put breakpoints up. Go through the code. See on which line is this code generated, See what that code is doing, provide context for it and share that snippet of code. (And I don't mean another line number)

Comment: http://answers.opencv.org/question/72099/getting-ncv-assertion-failed-error-ncv-stat28/ . can u see it here please.. am not able to post pics in my post